# Is not possible write from the map to hadoop file system (HDFS)

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs, mapper

I'm trying to write a plain text file in the hadoop file system directly from mapper.

I do it as follows:

```
public void createFile(Configuration conf) throws IOException{    
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

    Path filenamePath = new Path(conf.get("mapred.output.dir")+"/_"+conf.get("mapred.task.id"), "tree.txt");    

        try {

      if (fs.exists(filenamePath)) {        
        // remove the file first
        fs.delete(filenamePath);            
      }

      FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(filenamePath);       
      out.writeUTF("hello, world!");        
      out.close();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("IOException during operation: " + ioe.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

And it does not write anything in Pseudo-distributed mode. However, in stand-alone write perfectly.

Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  If the `Configuration` object passed in does not have the `fs.default.name` property it could be writing this file to local disk rather than HDFS.

Comment: Did you put logging statements in the code and look at the logs?

Answer (score 1):

I was using Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR) and I had to [get FileSystem by URI](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#get%28java.net.URI,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29) to be able to use files from S3.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(uri, conf);
```

That might not help you.